# psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aiopg

I am trying to execute simple query using sqlalchemy that basically just uses the `IN` clause in sql

Below is the query

```
select(Model).where(Model.column_name.in_(["test", "test1"]))
```

Below is the error i get

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 3: WHERE table_name.column_name IN ([POSTCOMPILE_column_name_1])
```

Comment: Probably due to [this issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg/issues/798).

Answer (score 0):

by orm

```
session.query(MODEL).filter(MODEL.col_name.in_((1,100))).all()
```

plain row:

```
session.execute(
    select(
        [MODEL.c.id, MODEL.c.name], 
        MODEL.c.id.in_((1, 100))
    )
).fetchall()
```

Comment: Already tried this solution but does not work

Comment: try to cast your list to tuple, i hope it'll helpful

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I was using `aiopg==0.16.0` but after upgradation to `aiopg==1.3.3` everything is working fine.